Guidance on keys for DynammoDB file/folder structure
I am working on a project that would be very similar to a standard file and folder system. The standard setup doesn't seem to difficult, but I have run into a couple of issues.
I have decided to set the pk to the ID of the parent of each time. The sk is the id for that item. In this manner, I can get all the contents of a folder by simply getting all items with that PK and I can get a specific item by using the PK and SK.
The access pattern that I can't quite figure out is this ...
I want to display the overall location like ...
Folder1 > Folder2 > Folder3 > File

I don't have access to how many folders are "above" the current location nor their names. I could simply query for those items, but that would require querying for each parent folder each time that file or folder is located.
I considered storing a separate entry that stores the hierarchy (all parents) for that file or a property that contains the hierarchy. That brings up the second problem. What happens when the user changes the name for Folder2 above? I would have to either update all hierarchies or query the parent in some way again.
Is it appropriate to store a flag that a folder has been changed? Wouldn't that just require more querying?
How do I handle this?

Have you considered using the S3 filesystem instead of DynamoDB? Why wouldn't S3 meet your needs?

This is just writing data to a database and then pulling it from there. Are you suggesting to just store json data in files and folders?
That sounds like it could be a permissions nightmare?

Why don't you build the hierarchy into DynamoDB.
Partition key being the root, and the sort key being the folders and files within that root.



PK
SK




Root1
Folder1


Root1
Folder1#File1


Root1
Folder2#Folder3#File1




I think this would mean that I query all children of the root each time. I only want to query the children of one folder at a time.

WHERE PK=Root1 AND SK begins_with Folder1#Folder2

So, if a user changes the name of a folder, wouldn't this require an update to all items that use that folder in their sk?

Yes, it would. But I would assume that isn't something that happens frequently. Query to get all of the items, and do a transaction of up to 100 items in a single request.

Can you point to the docs on this? How is that request made, etc?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html
